# Why isn't this excluding vowels?

Tags: java

This pulls from a word bank our teacher gave us, and I'm supposed to return the longest word without vowels. But it either returns a word with vowels or nothing at all. Please Help.

//What is the longest word with no vowels (counting y as a vowel)?

```
   public static void Question7()
   {  
     // return the number of words in wordlist ending in "ing"
     String longestWordSoFar = " ";
     System.out.println("Question 7:");
     int numberOfWords = 0; //count of words ending in ing
     for(int i = 1; i < WordList.numWords(); i++) // check every word in wordlist
        {
           if(noVowel(WordList.word(i))) { // if the length is greater than the previous word, replace it
           {

              if(WordList.word(i).length() > longestWordSoFar.length())            
                 longestWordSoFar=WordList.word(i);
              }      
           }

     }
     System.out.println("longest word without a vowel: " + longestWordSoFar);
     System.out.println();
     return;
   }
   public static boolean noVowel(String word) {
     //tells whether word ends in "ing"
        for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
           //doesnt have a vowel - return true
           if (word.charAt(i) != 'a') {
           return true;
           }
           if (word.charAt(i) != 'e') {
           return true;
           }
           if (word.charAt(i) != 'i') {
           return true;
           }
           if (word.charAt(i) != 'o') {
           return true;
           }
           if (word.charAt(i) != 'u') {
           return true;
           }
           if (word.charAt(i) != 'y') {
           return true;
           }

           }
        return false;
        }
```

Comment: Because you're running in a for loop, yet returning `true` on the first non-vowel character you'll encounter...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your method `noVowel`, you return `true` as soon as you find a character that is not `a`,`e`,`i`,`o`,`u`, or `y`. This is wrong. You'd rather return `false` as soon as you find one of these characters and only return `true` when there is none of them in the word.

Like this:

```
 public static boolean noVowel(String word) {
        for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
           //if a vowel found then return false
           if (word.charAt(i) == 'a') {
              return false;
           }
           if (word.charAt(i) == 'e') {
              return false;
           }
           if (word.charAt(i) == 'i') {
              return false;
           }
           if (word.charAt(i) == 'o') {
              return false;
           }
           if (word.charAt(i) == 'u') {
              return false;
           }
           if (word.charAt(i) == 'y') {
              return false;
           }

       }
    return true; // No vowel found, return true
}
```

Comment: Whenever I make all the vowels return false, it gives me a blank response.

Answer (score 0):

Change your noVowel method like:

```
public static boolean noVowel(String word) {
   boolean noVowel=true;
   for(int i=0;i<word.length();i++){
     char ch=word.charAt(i);
     if(ch=='a' ||ch=='e' ||ch=='i' ||ch=='o' ||ch=='u' ||ch=='y'){
       noVowel=false;
       break;
     }

   } 
    return noVowel;
}
```